# Angular 8 RouterLink opens the page as a whole instead of placing it inside the router outlet

Tags: angular8

```
<div class="col-md-9 docOprationDiv">
  <ul class="row"> 
    <span class="col-md oprations"><li style="padding-right: 0px;"><a style="text-decoration: none" 
       routerLink="/clinical-data">
     <span class="icon"><img src="../../../../assets/icons/New Icons/clinical data.svg">/span>
  </a></li></span>
  </ul>         
    <app-patient-preview></app-patient-preview>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>        

  <iframe class="col-md-12"  name="iframe_a" src="" style="height: 
     800px;width:1400px;border:none;">/iframe>
</div>
```

> I want the clinical-data page to be shown in the router-outlet not to load as a whole new page

Comment: Did you register this path in `RouterModule` along with component type?

Comment: yes I did. i think the problem is i used the router outlet outside of the app.component.html again.